# Adding data labels to points in ggplot: label argument not working

Tags: r, ggplot2

I know that this question has been answered a few times [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43176864/how-to-add-data-labels-to-ggplot) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23066039/ggplot-add-data-label-to-points). The key point seems to be to include the argument `label` in `aes`. But, for me ggplot does not accept `label` as an argument in `aes`. I tried using the generic function `labels` in aes as below, but that didn't work to create labels for points, though I am able to generate a graph:

```
  launch_curve <- ggplot(data = saltsnck_2002_plot_t,aes(x=weeks,y=markets, labels(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12))))+
    geom_line()+geom_point()+
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,12,by=1))+
    scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,50), breaks = seq(0,50,by=5))+
    xlab("Weeks since launch")+ ylab("No. of markets")+
    ggtitle(paste0(marker1,marker2))+
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 10))
  print(launch_curve)
```

Does anyone know a way around this? I am using R version 3.4.3.

**Edited to include sample data:**
The data that I use to plot is in the dataframe `saltsnck_2002_plot_t`. (12 rows by 94 cols). A sample is given below:

```
>saltsnck_2002_plot_t

       11410008398 11600028960 11819570760 11819570761 12325461033 12325461035 12325461037
Week1            3           2           2           1           2           2           1
Week2            6          16          10           1           3           2           2
Week3           11          41          13          10           3           3           2
Week4           15          46          14          14           3           4           4
Week5           15          48          15          14           3           4           4
Week6           27          48          15          15           3           4           4
Week7           31          50          15          15           3           4           5
Week8           33          50          16          16           5           5           6
Week9           34          50          18          16           5           5           6
Week10          34          50          21          19           5           5           6
Week11          34          50          23          21           5           5           6
Week12          34          50          24          23           5           5           6
```

I am actually plotting graphs in a loop by moving through the columns of the dataframe. This dataframe is the result of a transpose operation, hence the weird row and column names. The graph for the first column looks like the one below. And a correction from my earlier post, I need to capture as data labels the values in the column and not c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12).

[image]

Comment: Are you sure `labels(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12))` is a correct syntax. Also `dput` for reproducible data will be helpful.

Comment: The key point is to use `geom_text`, as in the answers to which you linked. Please include some data from `saltsnck_2002_plot_t` to make your problem reproducible.

Answer (score 4):

Use `geom_text`

```
library(ggplot2)  
ggplot(data = df,aes(x=weeks_num,y=markets))+
 geom_line() + geom_point() + geom_text(aes(label = weeks), hjust = 0.5,  vjust = -1) +
 scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,50), breaks = seq(0,50,by=5)) +
 scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1,12,by=1),labels = weeks_num)+
 xlab("Weeks since launch")+ ylab("No. of markets")+
 ggtitle(paste0(markets))+
 theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 10))
```

[image]

## Data

```
df <- structure(list(weeks_num = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
12), weeks = structure(1:12, .Label = c("week1", "week2", "week3", 
"week4", "week5", "week6", "week7", "week8", "week9", "week10", 
"week11", "week12"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), markets = c(3, 
 6, 11, 15, 27, 31, 33, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34)), .Names = c("weeks_num", 
"weeks", "markets"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```